# How to iterate dataframe´s index and columns in comprehension list?

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

If I need to iterate a `df` in a comprehension list, I would do this:

```
df['new_col'] = [x if y == 1 and z == 2 for x,y in df[['col_1', 'col_2']].values]
```

If instead of iterating `col_1` and `col_2`, I need to iterate `df.index` and `df_col_2` values?

What is the syntax inside the comprehension list in this `for` conditional example?

Comment: Why dont you use a simple df.loc solution instead of iterating thru the dataframe. Iterating is not a recommended solution to use in pandas

Comment: @Joe Ferndz in this simplified example you´re right. It is a simple computation. In other cases I need to iterate to perform a more complex conditionals.

Comment: Please share the complex problem statement. We have a good pool of Pandas experts in the community that can help you get this addressed without loops. Worst case we will all learn that the best solution is to use iterrows.

Comment: @Joe Ferndz I´m not a Pandas expert. If you say so I believe. Many times I use list comprehension when I have multiple conditions and possible outcomes. In this case the list-comprehension solution solves in one line code. Take this example, if it helps: `df_sic.swap_short_pct_y = [(1+c*d/a)**365-1 if (b == 'points' and a != 0) else c/100 if b == 'interest current' else aux.np.nan for a,b,c,d in df_sic[['bid', 'swap_mode', 'swap_short', 'tick_size']].values]`

Comment: If your dataframe is quite big then for loops can bring real performance issues. I would suggest you put your computation logic in function or lambda expression and use `parallel_apply` with axis=1 to apply it to each row in parallel. The downside is that you'll need to install an external package called `pandarallel` : https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel

Comment: @Alka great. I´ll study that. Thanks. Gotta improve this in my codes.

Comment: I am back online. Question for @DanielArges, are you checking for `index == 2`? What are you trying to achieve? If `col_1` is `1` and `col_2` is `2`, you want the index?. Also, `z` is not referenced in your loop, so where is `z` coming from? Same question for Aika on the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas dataframe and series have iteration methods. So to iterate over index and a given column you can use iteritems:

```py
df['new_col'] = [x if y == '1' and z =='2' for x, y in df['col_2'].iteritems()]
```

In this case x is the `index` and y the value of column `col2`

More generally `iterrows` gives you access to index and all columns in one iteration:

```py
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print("Index", idx)
    print("col1", row.col1)
    print("col2", row.col2)
    ...
```

Comment: Please try to provide solutions that do not use loops. This could be solved with df.loc if condition

Comment: How would you go with .loc in this particular case ?

Comment: @Alka something like this: `df.loc[df_dea.col_2 == '1', 'new_col'] = x`

Comment: @Alka, the answer from Daniel should do. I will share the solution later tonight when I am off work

Comment: I just noticed that the syntax isn't totally correct in your question @JoeFerndz, in list comprehension if you put your `if` at the beginning that means you must provide an `else` statement too, example `[i if i%2==0 else i*3 for i in range(10)]`; here you can't ommit the else : `[i if i%2==0 for i in range(10)]` won't work. I guess I just imagined the `else` was there and that's why I didn't propose the `.loc`. However if it is just a simple conditional assignment without `else`, then the proposed snippet by @Daniel is the right way to go

Comment: @Alka, where is `z` coming from? Is `z` an outside variable? or are you just using it based on what Daniel posted?

Comment: Yes @JoeFerndz, I just assumed it given what was in the question

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example of the dataframe. Then look at various things you can do with df.loc and df.index.

I will take a simple example of 5 kids ages 1 thru 4, and the points they have earned so far. Normally, I would prefer unique indexes but for this example we want you want to search by index. So I am making it nonunique.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Points': [2, 4, 8, 3, 2, 5, 6],
                   'Age': [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3]},
                  index=['Bob', 'Mike', 'Steve', 'Kate', 'Jane', 'Jill', 'Jane'])
                  
print (df)
```

The DataFrame will look like this:

```
       Points  Age
Bob         2    2
Mike        4    3
Steve       8    4
Kate        3    1
Jane        2    2
Jill        5    4
Jane        6    3
```

If we want to find all the kids with Age = 2 and name = Jane, you can give:

```
x = df.loc[(df.Age == 2) & (df.index == 'Jane'), 'Points'].tolist() #or .values

print (x)
```

Output will be:

```
[2]
```

If you want to find all the kids with Age = 2 and have scored 2 points, you can give:

```
y = df.index[(df.Age == 2) & (df.Points == 2)].tolist() #or .values

print (y)
```

Output will be:

```
['Bob', 'Jane']
```

If you want to find all the kids with Age = 3, you can give:

```
z = df.index[(df.Age == 3)].tolist() #or .values

print (z)
```

Output will be:

```
['Mike', 'Jane']
```

Let's say you want to narrow this down and update Jane aged 2 with Found in `New_col`, then you can give:

```
df.loc[(df.Age == 2) & (df.index == 'Jane'), 'New_col'] = 'Found'

print (df)
```

The outputs will be:

```
       Points  Age New_col
Bob         2    2     NaN
Mike        4    3     NaN
Steve       8    4     NaN
Kate        3    1     NaN
Jane        2    2   Found
Jill        5    4     NaN
Jane        6    3     NaN
```

None of these required us to iterate through the dataframe using df.iterrows(). We can do a lot of these data manipulation without the use of df.iterrows(). If you have a specific usecase, let's review it and come up with a solution that does not involve iteration.